# Azure logical app current time

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, workflow-definition-language

I have an Azure Logical app that every hour gets a file from a website and create a file in OneDrive. Since the file does not have a dynamic name, it gets replaced every time. Is there a way to put the current date time in the filename?

Thank you,
David

Comment: if you are using File connector or Onedrive connector when you call the PUT method to upload the file you will be passing the full filepath including the filename right. You can append the  @{utcnow()} to the filepath.  utcnow() function provides the current UTC time . https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/create-connectors-in-logic-apps-designer/

Answer (score 8):

[@Rodrigo Daruich Alvarez's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49266422/3649914) answer got me in the right direction but the  format wasn't quite right. The below worked for me

```
concat('file',string(utcNow('yyyyMMdd'),'xls')
```

the formDataValue didn't seem to work.

documentation [here](https://www.o365dude.com/2017/05/01/working-with-dates-times-in-microsoft-flow/)

Comment: `yyyyMMdd` (`MM` is months, `mm` is minutes)

Answer (score 0):

you can add dynamic content on filename input:

[file logic apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CcD3.png)

and add expresion:

```
concat('file',string(formDataValue(utcNow(),'yyyyMMdd')),'xls')
```

Comment: doesn't seem to like the `formDataValue` function - getting as error

Comment: Plus one  for getting me on the right direction though.